# html canvas shadow being applied to everything

Tags: html, canvas, shadow

If you define a shadow ONCE, then it applies to all "graphics" on the canvas from thereon after (which is what it's supposed to do).

Sample:
http://flanvas.com/development/flanvas/test.html

Does anyone know best practice to turn the shadow off after you've used it? I'm setting shadowColor to "rgba(0,0,0,0)" which is a no-alpha black. I'm sure there is a better way.

case sample: The text is also getting a shadow. I'm using the no-alpha black to combat this for now.
http://flanvas.com/development/flanvas/examples/filters-dropShadowFilter.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

By using `save`, `translate` and `restore` you can perform your tasks without worrying about the style changes, for eg.

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(X,Y);

ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)';

// do some stuff

ctx.restore();
```

here `X` & `Y` are the co-ordinates where you intended to draw and you do your stuff relative to the co-ordinates `0,0`.

This method solves the problem of caching and restoring the previous styles/values and is also very helpful when you work with gradients as they are always plotted relative to the origin `(0,0)`

Comment: Excellent point. This solution works really nicely in more complex cases (less things to keep track of).

Comment: @Livingston Samuel, do you know if this has any effect on performance?

Comment: there are performance implications of using `save` and `restore`, especially when used in the main loop.

If performance is primary focus, using an offscreen canvas to render and using that as a sprite would be better.

If you want to only set the transform origin, then using `setTransform` instead would be better.

Answer (score 11):

(EDIT: Oops! I see that's what you were already doing with a 0 alpha black.)

This is what you were looking for:

```
context.shadowColor = "transparent";
```

Answer (score 6):

It's usually a good idea to store the old value of these kind of "global" attributes before you change it and use this stored value to restore it later on. Example:

```
var origShadowColor = ctx.shadowColor;
ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)';

// ... do some stuff

ctx.shadowColor = origShadowColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function i can call to reset the shadow if needed.

```
resetShadow() {
    this.ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    this.ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
    this.ctx.shadowColor = "transparent";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `console.log(ctx.shadowColor, ctx.shadowBlur)` on a new canvas context, without being modified, you can see the default values as `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` for the color and `0` for the blur.

Doing `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` does the trick too, be is more expensive since it has to save all the context for each saves you do.

So you're doing right, there's technically no better way.